# How could I form a regular expression in which in some cases it starts with * and in others not in python

Tags: python

Good morning I have a question about a regular expression that I am forming the question is that what I want to capture in some cases starts with * and in others not, example:

```
*B:P79COL01 #

 A:PED77MCY04 #
```

The regular expression I am using to capture this value is as follows:

pattern = re.compile (f '[/ *] [AB]: {equipo} #?')

Where equipo is a variable

but I can't get the values ​​that I don't start with * (example A: PED77MCY03 #), I really am new with regular expressions and I can hardly understand it

```
equipo='P79COL01'
patron=re.compile(f'[/*][AB]:{equipo}#?')
```

Comment: try `[/*]?`. the `?` means it is optional. Although it seems to me you can just do: `equipo in text`

Comment: ```[*]{0,1}``` or ```[*]?```.

Comment: It worked for me. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\*?[AB]:(.*?) #
```

Could work.

`\*` escapes the * character allowing us to match it.

`?` matches 0 or 1 occurrences of the preceding character, which seems to be the core issue of your issue.

`(.*?)` matches anything between the `:` and the `#`. ( Note the space before # as in your above example )
With the result being its own capture group.

[{0,1} and ? seem to be the same](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#repeating-things) but may make sense to go with the latter for readability, but there is freedom here and it seems down to personal choice - just as both options were listed in a comment.

Definitely worth having a general look through [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#repeating-things) for any tweaks and slight alterations.